# Functions without arguments

Tags: r, function

I'm not sure about this. Here is an example of a function which does not work:

```
myfunction<-function(){
mydata=read_excel("Square_data.xlsx", sheet = "Data", skip=0)
mydata$Dates=as.Date(mydata$Dates, format= "%Y-%m-%d")
mydata.ts=ts(mydata, start=2006, frequency=1)
}
```

The files do not load. When I execute each command line by line in R the files are loaded, so there's no problem with the commands. My question is, can I run a function such as myfunction to load the files? Thanks.

Comment: How are you running your function? And what do you want to return? The data? The time-series?

Comment: You might try to use the super-assignment operator `<<-` instead of `= `to make `mydata` available outside the scope of the function.

Comment: Heroka, I want to return two files mydata and mydata.ts.

Comment: FlooO, not sure I follow?

Comment: @FarmerGeorge Did you try what I suggested in my comment? Replace all `= ` with `<<-` and things should work as you expect.

Comment: @RHertel - that did the trick. I wasn't aware of the super-assignment operator <<-. Will read-up on its role. Many thanks for that, appreciated.

Comment: You should also be able to return them both in one list: `return(list(obj1, obj2))`. Btw: Why are you putting it into a function?

Comment: @lukeA. First, and I wanted to see if I could load different files via a function and secondly, it seemed a convenient way to load files.

Comment: I see, I also asked that if you used it for structuring, you could also check out RStudio and its [sections](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections) feature.

Comment: @lukeA, the return() function will only list the data, but not put the files into the workspace.

Comment: @lukeA - I use RStudio - it's a great facility. Only stumbled across the folding capability last week - all of my script files now look very tidy, all with clear headings. I no longer have continuous lines of script running into hundreds.

Comment: Just remove the function completely. Unless this is nested in another function or some other complicated structure, there is no need for this script to be a function.

Comment: @Pierre, so, you are saying it's pointless having a function which loads specific files? How would you do it?

Comment: @FarmerGeorge you can put those commands in a separate script and `source` it, for example.

Comment: @docendodiscimus, which is what I already do. Also, why not have many functions, which call in different files, have them all collected together in a single script called loading_files, say, and then select the one which is of interest. Ok, I know I can also  make use of the folding facility in Rstdio. I like the functions apparoch which I can now do. There are many ways to skin a cat, depending on preferences.

Answer (score 6):

**Last statement in function is an assignment** If the last executed statement in a function is an assignment then it will not display on the console unless you use `print` but if the function result is assigned then you can print the assigned value later.  For example, using the built in `BOD` data frame:

```
> f <- function() bod <- BOD
> f() # no result printed on console because f() was not explicitly printed
> print(f()) # explicitly print
  Time demand
1    1    8.3
2    2   10.3
3    3   19.0
4    4   16.0
5    5   15.6
6    7   19.8
> X <- f() # assign and then print the assigned value
> X
  Time demand
1    1    8.3
2    2   10.3
3    3   19.0
4    4   16.0
5    5   15.6
6    7   19.8
```

**Last statement in function is expression producing a result** If the last statement produces a value rather than being an assignment then a result is printed on the console.  For example:

```
> g <- function() BOD
> g()
  Time demand
1    1    8.3
2    2   10.3
3    3   19.0
4    4   16.0
5    5   15.6
6    7   19.8
```

Thus make sure that the last statement in your function is not an assignment if you want it to display on the console automatically.

**Note 1: sourcing code** Also, note that if your code is sourced using a `source()` statement or if the code is called by another function then it also won't print automatically on the console unless you use a `print`.

**Note 2: Two results** Regarding some comments to the question, if you want to output two results then output them in a named list.  For example.  this outputs a list with components named BOD and BOD2:

```
h <- function() list(BOD = BOD, BOD2 = 2*BOD)
h()
$BOD
  Time demand
1    1    8.3
2    2   10.3
3    3   19.0
4    4   16.0
5    5   15.6
6    7   19.8

$BOD2
  Time demand
1    2   16.6
2    4   20.6
3    6   38.0
4    8   32.0
5   10   31.2
6   14   39.6
```

We could refer to them like this:

```
> H <- h()
> H$BOD
  Time demand
1    1    8.3
2    2   10.3
3    3   19.0
4    4   16.0
5    5   15.6
6    7   19.8
> H$BOD2
  Time demand
1    2   16.6
2    4   20.6
3    6   38.0
4    8   32.0
5   10   31.2
6   14   39.6
```

**Note 3: <<- operator** Regarding the comments to the question, in general, using the `<<-` operator should be avoided because it undesirably links the internals of your function to the global workspace in an invisible and therefore error-prone way.  If you want to return a value it is normally best to return it as the output of the function.  There are some situations where `<<-` is warranted but they are relatively uncommon.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use a `function` with no arguments or would you have an example of where its really useful? If you aren't passing an argument, its very similar (if not the same?) as putting lines of R code in a script and calling `source` - would this be a fair assumption or do I have it wrong? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just give it a value to be returned:

```
myfunction<-function(){
mydata=read_excel("Square_data.xlsx", sheet = "Data", skip=0)
mydata$Dates=as.Date(mydata$Dates, format= "%Y-%m-%d")
ts(mydata, start=2006, frequency=1) # The last object is returned by an R function
}
```

so calling `dat <- myfunction()` will make `dat` the ts-object that was created inside the function.

P.S.: There also in a `return` function in **R**. As a best practice only use this if you want to return an object *early*, e.g. in combination with `if`

Comment: OP wants two assignments `mydata` and `mydata.ts`.